# Pass PHP variable to JavaScript over AJAX (chat app)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

heyo!

I'm trying to create a chat app for my website which has users (registration, login etc). I'm using NodeJS as the chat server so I can use SocketIO with it.

I have a index.php, in which I have set up a form with a text field and a submit button.
To retrieve the username I have this handy piece of code in the top:

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So I can access the username by `$row['userName'];`

I've done so as well in my insertMessage.php, so inserting the username with the message into the database works fine.
But I don't know how to figure it out in the client.js, which has the following code:

```
    $( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
    var nameVal = $( ); <-------- don't know what to put in here :S
    var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();

    socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

    $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/insertMessage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });

    return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
    var newMsgContent = 'Name: ' + data.name + ' Message:' + data.message;
    var content = actualContent + newMsgContent;

    $( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

My form:

```
    <form class="input-group" id="messageForm">
  <input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Type message..." class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" value="Send"></input>
  </span>
</form>
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Nobody else knows what to put there either because you didn't post any information about what your HTML form looks like.

Comment: I used the code from a tutorial, and in that tutorial there is not only the message text field, but also a username text field. But since I already have a user system, I want to get rid of that username field, but I really don't know how to do so, and googling about "transfer PHP variables into javascript" confused me even more. :S

Comment: You're the only person who knows where that "username" value is supposed to come from. Is it a form field? Something in your client-side framework? Something else?

Comment: I wrote in the question: "So I can access the username by $row['userName'];"

Comment: sorry i make mistake, i didnt read correcty. can you give us your HTML like @Pointy said. if you used code from tutorial, give us a link. because only god, you, and the tutorial writer know that nameVal value (NOTE: i already deleted my answer)

Comment: https://github.com/jdutheil/nodePHP/blob/master/index.php
This is the full code, I added my form code on my question

Comment: try `var nameVal = $("nameInput").val();`

Comment: Thats the standard variable, I want to get rid of the nameInput text field. I have users added to my MySQL database and I can get the current users name by $row['userName']; (whereas userName is the username row in my database)

Comment: *Somehow* your server-side code needs to know what user is communicating from a client. That's usually a matter of keeping a secure session kept in a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i imagine you have something like this $_SESSION['username'] .

optional 1:
put in the hidden input 
`<input id="nameInput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>" type="hidden"  />` then `var nameVal = $('#nameInput').val();`

optional 2:
direct write in jquery script
`var nameVal = <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>;`

**update** for optional 2:
if you have separate javascript file. you can do this:

```
<script>
var nameVal= <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>; //do this rigth before you call js script that will process this var.
</script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

thats basically like `include` or `require` in PHP

Comment: The question title is indeed "pass PHP variable into ajax", but the content of the question seems to be the exact opposite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there a way to set var nameVal to the username, instead of calling an alert?

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work since it's a client.js file, but the first option with setting a hidden input works perfect! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

When you are inserting data into the database just send the text message. Retrieve the user who sent the message from the session.

```
// Send only the message
// in insertMessage.php retrieve the user from session.
// in response send the username and the message back to the client as json
// after retrieving the response you can emit your socket event
$.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/insertMessage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { message: msg },
        success: function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            username = data.username;
            message = data.message;
            socket.emit( 'message', { name: username, message: message} );
        }
    });
```

Although not the most ideal solution, you can definitely give it a try.